# Trying to get additional information from Map Annotations-swift

Tags: iphone, swift, uitableview, mkmapview, mkannotation

I am trying to make a simple app that has a map and some fixed annotations. I want to click those annotations, their button, and get a menu with a picture and some additional text like how the Apple Maps points work.

So far here is my code, I can get all the way to the DetailDisclosure Button, but I cannot get it to work that way when I click it. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

(there is also a class called `Shops`, but I haven't included in this post)

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate,  UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

var mapItemData:MKMapItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Initiate GPS

    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    //Pin coordinates

    mapView.delegate = self

    let J = Shops(title: "Jingle", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 44.631076, longitude: 22.946770), info: "H", address:"Π", subtitle:"κ")
    let K = Shops(title: "R", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 43.65, longitude: 6.43), info: "F", address:"Π", subtitle:"κ")
    let L = Shops(title: "P", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 58.89, longitude: 2.3508), info: "O", address:"Π", subtitle:"κ")
    let B = Shops(title: "R", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 26, longitude: 17), info: "H", address:"Π", subtitle:"κ")
    let W = Shops(title: "W", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 88.43111, longitude: -37.035663), info: "N", address:"Π", subtitle:"κ")

    mapView.addAnnotations([J, K, L, B, W])
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// Locate through GPS

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations.last
    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 1, longitudeDelta: 1))

    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    let identifier = "Shops"
    if annotation.isKindOfClass(Shops.self) {
        var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(identifier)
        if annotationView == nil {
            annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
            annotationView!.canShowCallout = true
            let btn = UIButton(type: .InfoLight)
            annotationView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = btn

        }else{
            annotationView!.annotation = annotation
    }

    return annotationView
}
    return nil
}
//Zoom out to enclose all annotations

func fitMapViewToAnnotaionList(annotations: [MKPointAnnotation]) -> Void            {
    let mapEdgePadding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 20, bottom: 20, right: 20)
    var zoomRect:MKMapRect = MKMapRectNull

    for index in 0..<annotations.count {
        let annotation = annotations[index]
        let aPoint:MKMapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate)
        let rect:MKMapRect = MKMapRectMake(aPoint.x, aPoint.y, 0.1, 0.1)

        if MKMapRectIsNull(zoomRect) {
            zoomRect = rect
        } else {
            zoomRect = MKMapRectUnion(zoomRect, rect)
        }
    }

    mapView.setVisibleMapRect(zoomRect, edgePadding: mapEdgePadding, animated: true)
}

}
```

Comment: I do not see your implementation of `mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:`, and your button has no target-action, so I don't see why you expect anything to happen.

Comment: You are absolutely right about that Matt, I now added a simple function to handle that. My main problem though is the code that creates the menu. What can I do about that?
Thanks in advance